# Not Able to Add Breaks For Feature Service Graphics

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-service

Using ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.24, can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know why I am not able to add Symbology to Feature Service out put by using `ClassBreaksRenderer`

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>FeatureLayer</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/"></script>

<style>
html, body, #map {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<script>
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/Color",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(
    Map,
     FeatureLayer,
     ClassBreaksRenderer,
     SimpleMarkerSymbol,
     SimpleLineSymbol,
     SimpleFillSymbol,
     Color
  ) {

    var map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "hybrid",
      center: [-82.44109, 35.6122],
      zoom: 17
    });

    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Landscape_Trees/FeatureServer/0",{
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
            outFields: [ "*" ]   

    });
   var observationRenderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(new SimpleMarkerSymbol(), "Ht_DBH_ft");
    observationRenderer.addBreak(3, 6,  new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,
    new Color([12,255,12]), 2),new Color([12,255,12,1])
  ));
    observationRenderer.addBreak(0, 3,  new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,
    new Color([255,0,0]), 2),new Color([128,255,128,1])
  ));

    map.addLayer(featureLayer);

  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not define a marker symbol for the two break classes. Instead, you used SimpleFillColor to the geometries of that feature layer, which are **Points**. So, you will not see any results.
Plus, you forgot to apply your renderer to the feature Layer.

First, define the default SimpleMarkerSymbol :

```
var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
  SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND,
  5,
  new SimpleLineSymbol(
    SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new Color([255,0,0]), 1
  ),
  new Color([255,0,0,0.25])
);
```

Create your renderer and apply to it the default symbol :

`var observationRenderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(symbol, "Ht_DBH_ft");`

Now, define your break classes :

```
observationRenderer.addBreak(0, 3,
  new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
    SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND,
    10,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(
      SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
      new Color([0,255,0]), 1
    ),
    new Color([0,255,0,0.25])
  )
);

observationRenderer.addBreak(3, 6,
  new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
    SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND,
    50,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(
      SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
      new Color([0,0,255]), 1
    ),
    new Color([0,0,255,0.25])
  )
);
```

Apply your completed renderer to the feature layer :

`featureLayer.setRenderer(observationRenderer);`

Add that layer to the map :

`map.addLayer(featureLayer);`